# Why a bounded trajectory must converge for a scalar ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why a bounded trajectory must converge for a scalar ODE ? Why can't it just oscillate ?

For example, consider the ODE:

$$\bar{x}(t) = p(x(t)) - x(t)$$ where $p$ is a continuous function taking values in $[0,1]$. So, any trajectory satisfying this is bounded. Will it converge to an equilibrium

Comment: @user148951: why downvote ?

Comment: So by $\bar x(t)$ you mean $dx(t)/dt$?

Comment: @RobertLewis: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation $x'=F(x)$ with initial condition $x(0)=\xi$ where $F\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous.

- If $F(\xi)=0$ then the solution is constant.
- If $F(\xi)>0$ the the solution is strictly increasing.
- If $F(\xi)<0$ the the solution is strictly decreasing.

In all cases, if the solution is bounded it converges as $t\to\pm\infty$.

The situation is more delicate if $F$ is merely continuous and uniqueness does not hold. A solution may increase up to a point and then become constant. It may start to increase again, become constant once more and so on. But it cannot attain a maximum and decrease.

Comment: Aguirre : extremely sorry. it was given as lipschitz continuous.

Comment: No problem. My answer covers both cases.